# How to convert a text file to xml with sub elements in java

Tags: java, xml

I saw this code posted on another thread but cannot get this to convert a text file to format correctly to xml with sub-elements. Rather than output a simple xml

From this:

```
Example One
Example Two
Example Three
```

To this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <inserts>
    <option>Example One</option>
    <option>Example Two</option>
    <option>Example Three</option>
  </inserts>
```

I need the following conversion from a text file:

```
 first_main_elem
 f_child_elem1:one
 f_child_elem2:two
 second_main_elem
 s_child_elem1:one
 s_child_elem1:two
 third_standalone_element: null value
 fourth_element:stand alone
```

to:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <first_main_elem>
      <f_child_elem1>one</f_child_elem1>
       <f_child_elem1>two</f_child_elem1>
        <f_child_elem1>three</f_child_elem1>
  </first_main_element>
  <second_main_elem>
         <s_child_elem1>one</s_child_elem>
         <s_child_elem2>two</s_child_elem2>
   </second_main_elem>
   <fourth_standalone_elem/> 
   <fifth_element>stand alone</fifth_element>
```

the code posted:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.*;

 public class ToXML {

 BufferedReader in;
 StreamResult out;
 TransformerHandler th;

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    new ToXML().begin();
}

 public void begin() {
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        out = new StreamResult("data.xml");
        openXml();
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            process(str);
        }
         in.close();
         closeXml();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

      public void openXml() throws ParserConfigurationException,TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException{ 

    SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory)SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
    th = tf.newTransformerHandler();

    // pretty XML output
    Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

    th.setResult(out);
    th.startDocument();
    th.startElement(null, null, "inserts", null);
}

   public void process(String s) throws SAXException {
    th.startElement(null, null, "option", null);
    th.characters(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length());
    th.endElement(null, null, "option");
  }

  public void closeXml() throws SAXException {
    th.endElement(null, null, "inserts");
    th.endDocument();
   }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions or advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

draft version please find below but improve more about parsing empty nodes:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.TransformerHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ToXML {

    BufferedReader in;
    StreamResult out;
    TransformerHandler th;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ToXML().begin();
    }

    public void begin() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "data.txt"));
            out = new StreamResult("data.xml");

            openXml();
            String str;

            String[] elements = null;

            // skip first line in input file
            in.readLine();

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                if (str.contains(":")) {
                    elements = str.split(":");
                    process(elements[0], elements[1]);

                } else {
                    th.startElement(null, null, str, null);
                }
            }
            in.close();
            closeXml("first_main_elem");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openXml() throws ParserConfigurationException,
            TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {

        SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        th = tf.newTransformerHandler();

        // pretty XML output
        Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(
                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        th.setResult(out);
        th.startDocument();
        th.startElement(null, null, "first_main_elem", null);
    }

    public void process(String tag, String s) throws SAXException {
        th.startElement(null, null, tag, null);
        th.characters(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length());
        th.endElement(null, null, tag);
    }

    public void closeXml(String s) throws SAXException {
        th.endElement(null, null, s);
        th.endDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bhargav - I'll try this